# How can I disable the "Install update to keep device running smoothly" notification?

Tags: updates, popup, systemless-root

Once every few weeks, I get this notification to update the device after unlocking my phone.

[image]

I have automatic updates disabled in system settings as well. Hoping there is a service that a "root service disabler" app could disable to put an end to these notifications.

My device is rooted and on Android 11.

Comment: This is not a notification. A notification does not look like that. Since you didn't share the full screenshot it is hard to tell what that UI element. It could be an activity or a dialog. Activities can be disabled easily with root. Dialogs, not so. OTOH, if there is a System Update app then disabling it usually solves the problem too. In Settings -> Apps -> App apps, do you see an app named something as Update or System update. Have you tried disabling it and restarting the phone to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: I might have accidentally found [your thread on XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-block-incremental-updates-on-android-10-with-root.4180053/), and looks like you're using a rooted Essential phone? I also found [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/essential/comments/dihxef/comment/f3woiyt/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that said even Essential phone on LineageOS also got the same dialog, and it might be related to Google Play Services.

Comment: @AndrewT. Haha yes you did. The Phone is a Google Pixel 4 XL on Android 11 (per the signature on XDA actually) and from what I read "essentials" is also part of the Google Play Services notification section. I saw on there that I had "~1 Setup" notification so I disabled that. Will see if that was what this popup was. Probably will take a week or two before I see it again anyway so will have to wait a bit and keeping this question open.

Comment: @AndrewT. Updated the thread with a new picture. I only have "all alerts" and "account" notifications turned on in the Google Play app notification settings also. Just got the alert today again.

Comment: Eli Billauer wrote [an extensive blog article](https://billauer.co.il/blog/2022/08/android-turn-off-system-update/) about preventing Android system update, including disabling the popup. You might want to check and try it.

Answer (score -1):

Methinks this thing is a virus. It's not a notification that stock Android would ever issue. I had the same problem a while back whilst still using a Pixel 3, not jailbroken. This was before Google stopped issuing security updates; I was running Android 12, Build number SP1A.210812.016.C2.

Every Saturday at 17:00, I'd get the same pop-up message that you did (see pic). I never installed the "update" of course; tapping outside the pop-up screen made it disappear for another week - But it continued to reappear every Saturday at 17:00 (I'm in the Eastern USA time zone).

When I upgraded to a Pixel 5a (which I'm still using) I chose to *not* copy everything from the Pixel 3; It was a pain, but I just manually installed all the apps I wanted. Then, I did a factory reset on the old Pixel 3, re-installed Android 12 via the standard System interface, and the pop-up never reappeared.

I have no idea how this thing got on my phone, if in fact it is a virus. Possibly steganography attack via an image file? In any event, I humbly recommend that you start fresh with a new phone or wipe the one you're using and start over. Good luck...

[image: Screenshot of popup message]

Comment: AFAIK, this is not a virus, but [a dialog by Google Play Services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247975/i-keep-seeing-a-popup-in-android-install-now-to-control-when-your-device-updat?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment333072_247975) notifying that the device has pending updates.

Comment: Interesting - But golly, it looks suspicious. What's still odd is that the prompt disappeared after I did a factory reset and reinstalled the exact same operating system version...